# Laravel 5 Scheduler Caching permission issue

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a scheduler which caches to file. 
This data is then picked up by a user when they visit a particular page.

The issue I'm having is that the scheduler is saving to the cache with the user ubuntu and the user is trying to pull this from the cache with the www-data user which leads to file permission problems.

Anyone have a decent solution to this other than setting a crontab to periodically update the cache folder permissions?

Comment: Why don't you place ubuntu and www-data in the same user group?

Comment: I could, but I was hoping to find a solution within Laravel. Some way of setting the user:group if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this problem also. I've resolved this by running the artisan queue: commands as the user that owns the files. For example:

`sudo -u apache ./artisan queue:restart`

or

`sudo -u apache ./artisan queue:flush`

This prevents permissions issues since my apache user owns the storage directory and writes all the files.